# Как узнать на сайте ли пользователь или нет?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp, asp.net-identity-2

То есть как в вк:  проверяется на сайте ли пользователь, и потом пишет.
И мне интересно как это делается. 
Знает ли кто эту страшную тайну?

Comment: Ну а вообще ничего не мешает вам просто обновлять дату последнего визита при любом запросе от пользователя

Comment: @andreymal ну он же может просто открыть сайт, и будет отображаться, что он не на сайте.

Comment: В случае с ВК именно это и происходит :)

Comment: @andreymal ну ладно :)

Comment: Но если делать не как в ВК, а по-умному, то можно сделать вебсокеты. Пользователь подключен к вебсокету — значит он онлайн, не подключен — оффлайн. (Информации про вебсокеты навалом в интернете, хотя конкретно про asp.net не знаю)

Comment: Что забавно, даже при переключении разных вкладок в личных сообщениях ВК продолжает считать, что я оффлайн

Comment: @andreymal единственный баг ВК :)

Comment: @VerNick, надеюсь, `единственный` - это очень смешная шутка хД

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В случае VK, если говорить про почту, используется Long Polling, отправляются запросы на **imxxx** и **al_im.php**.

Т.е, если неплохая достаточно точность нужна, то клиент должен пинговать сервак периодически.

Если точность особо не важна, то можно запоминать последнее время, когда человек заходил на сайт или когда посылал к серваку последний запрос. Это и будет, по сути, временем, когда человек последний раз был онлайн.